# Data Usage Forecasting

Tags: tasks, data-export, data-storage

The company I work for is quickly approaching their data storage limit. Thinking about upgrading their storage. However before hand they are trying to estimate out how much they might need. I can see that most of the storage is from tasks. (Which a deletion plan need to happen)

Is there any way to run a report of data storage over time?

Comment: if Tasks are the culprit, you could do a summary (or matrix) report on Task showing # created by month and make some assumptions about the average Task size (if they have attachments or not). It is not uncommon that Tasks are the culprit (or something related to marketing automation systems)

Comment: tasks are auto archived if they are more than 365 days old and not accessible via GUI. 
So what I can suggest is take a backup of those records and delete those records from salesforce.